# Hibernate : Change in the process flow of unprox object in between JDK7 and JDK8

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, java-8

In my project I need to unproxy the hibernate object and I used the unproxying method as given below In JDK 1.7.0.45 it was working fine But couple of weeks ago We have updated our JDK version to 1.8.0.121 and starting getting the following problem

**Entity Classes**

```
public abstract class Employee {

    private Long key;

    private Map<String, Rating> ratingsMap;

    public Employee() {
        super();
    }

    public void setRatingsMap(Map<String, Rating> ratingsMap) {
        this.ratingsMap = ratingsMap;
    }

    public Map<String, Rating> getRatingsMap() {
        return ratingsMap;
    }
}

abstract public class AbstractRating {

 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String identifier;

    private Integer ranking;

    private String name;

    private String description;

}

public class Rating extends AbstractRating {

    private RatingScale ratingScale;
}
```

**Rating.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd"
        [
            <!ENTITY commonfilters SYSTEM "classpath://common.include.xml">
        ]
    >
<hibernate-mapping package="com.mypackage.model">
<class name="AbstractRating" table="CPD_RATING">
<id name="key" type="long">
            <column name="CPD_RATING_SEQNUM" sql-type="number" />
            <generator class="org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator">
                <param name="optimizer">com.mypackage.hibernate.id.enhanced.PooledOptimizerMT</param>
                <param name="increment_size">1000</param>
                <param name="sequence_name">SQ_CPD_RATING</param>
            </generator>
        </id>

        <subclass name="Rating" discriminator-value="TALENT_ASSESSMENT">
            <many-to-one name="ratingScale" class="RatingScale">
                <column name="CPD_RATING_SCALE_SEQNUM" sql-type="number" not-null="true" unique-key="XIE1CPD_RATING"/>
            </many-to-one>
        </subclass>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Employee.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd"
        [
            <!ENTITY commonfilters SYSTEM "classpath://common.include.xml">
        ]
    >
<hibernate-mapping package="com.mypackage.model">
    <class name="Employee" table="EMPLOYEE" abstract="true">
        <id name="key" type="long">
            <column name="EMP_SEQNUM" sql-type="number"/>
            <generator class="org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator">
                <param name="optimizer">com.workscape.hibernate.id.enhanced.PooledOptimizerMT</param>
                <param name="increment_size">1000</param>
                <param name="sequence_name">SQ_EMPLOYEE</param>
            </generator>
        </id>

        <!-- Map to store the transfered talent assessment values -->    
        <map name="ratingsMap" table="EMP_RATING">
            <key column="EMP_SEQNUM"/>
            <map-key column="SCALE_ID" type="string" length="100"/>
            <many-to-many column="RATING_SEQNUM" class="com.workscape.scale.model.Rating"/>
        </map>
    </class>    
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Method to unprox the Object**

```
public abstract class PersistentObject {
    public static <T extends PersistentObject> T unproxy(Object proxy) {
        T unproxied = null;
        Hibernate.initialize(proxy);
        if(proxy instanceof HibernateProxy) {
            unproxied = (T)((HibernateProxy)proxy)
                .getHibernateLazyInitializer().getImplementation();
        } else {
            return (T) proxy;
        }

        return unproxied;
    }   
}
```

**EmployeeRatingUpdaterServiceImpl.java**

```
public class EmployeeRatingUpdaterServiceImpl {

     public void updateRating(Employee employee, String ratingScaleId, Rating rating) {
     employee = PersistentObject.unproxy( employee);

     Map<String, Rating> ratingsMap = employee.getRatingsMap(); 

    if(ratingsMap == null) {
        //This is the first time talent assessment ratings are transfered into comp
        ratingsMap = new HashMap<String, Rating>();
    }

    //add or update the rating
    ratingsMap.put(ratingScaleId, dataSetRating);
    employee.setRatingsMap(ratingsMap);
}
```

Now in ***updateRating()*** method I am getting the null value for the `ratingsMap` of an passed employee object.

```
public class EmployeeServiceImpl {
    private EmployeeRatingUpdaterService employeeRatingUpdaterService;

    public void updateRating(Employee employee) {
        Map<String, Rating> lookUpRatings = xyzProvider.lookUpRatings();
        for(Map.Entry<String, Rating> entry : lookUpRatings.entrySet()) {
            employeeRatingUpdaterService.updateRating(employeeCompensation, entry.getKey(),
                                                      entry.getValue());
        }
        //NOTE : JDK 1.8 Issue here I am getting ratingsMap of employee object as null it was working fine in JDK1.7
    }   
}
```

> Now to solve this issue I have updated above method as

```
public void updateRating(Employee employee) {
        Map<String, Rating> lookUpRatings = xyzProvider.lookUpRatings();
      //NOTE : FIX for the issue 
      employee = PersistentObject.unproxy( employee);
      for(Map.Entry<String, Rating> entry : lookUpRatings.entrySet()) {
            employeeRatingUpdaterService.updateRating(employeeCompensation, entry.getKey(),
                                                      entry.getValue());
        }
    }
```

I am not sure what is the change in the process of unproxying an object in JDK1.8 ?

Hibernate Version : 4.2.6.Final
Spring Version : 4.2.1.RELEASE

Any help regarding this will be appreciated

Comment: what following error?

Comment: @Eugene I mean following problem 
Problem : I am getting the ratingsMap of employee object is null but it was not null at the end of employeeRatingUpdaterService method ? It is fixed  when I have passed unproxy() object to updateRating() method of EmployeeServiceImpl  class.